# How can I, using tsql, validate the format of a json string being saved to a column in table?

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql

I have a column where a JSON string is stored. How can I validate that what is being saved is actually a valid JSON string?

Comment: Microsoft announced support for JSON starting with SQL Server 2016 so that would probably come with native validation mechanisms. Otherwise, in current and past versions there isn't a native way to validate a string that is actually a JSON (such as with XML in example), when you deliver it to a column. You could try to write a stored procedure that takes the string as input and do some shoveling there..

Comment: Save yourself a lot of wasted effort and just validated it before inserting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following article should you wish to pursue this long, arduous route.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Good article, but it is a bit of an overkill. I do not want to parse the content, just make sure it is a valid JSON that could be parsed later on by JavaScript (not tsql).

Comment: By validating I mean just checking that the content is formed correctly (as specified in RFC 4627) not checking the actual values of the content.